# Vertical centering and cropping image with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, resolution

I have gallery with couple of images who has that size: 1600px × 1042px

I cut and centers images on site using that styles in css:

```
.graphic-container img {margin-top: -22%; margin-bottom: -22%;}
```

For someone who screen resolution is higher than 1600px I include that jquery code to the site:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      resizeDiv();

  window.onresize = function(event) {
      resizeDiv();
  }

  function resizeDiv() {
      document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
      vpw = $(window).width(); 
      vph = $(window).height(); 
      $('#featured .csc-imagewrap img').css({'width': vpw + 'px'});
  }

});
</script>
```

But when under the gallery is some more content, the person who viewing the site don't see the whole content, because the right scroller is disabled.

I know that the line `document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";` made this, but when I disable that line I have 15px white line on right side of the gallery (because the images has higher height than the screen resolution).

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set

`overvlow: hidden;`

for the wrapping div container via css and then remove

```
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
```

from your js.

Comment: I have that style in my css: `.graphic-container {overflow: hidden; background-size: contain; position: relative;}`

Comment: You should also define height and width of the wrapper. If you dont set a height the div gets expanded. Try to set 'height: 100%;'

Comment: I make that site in responsive web design, and that solution break my gallery

Comment: set the height via js in your resize div function. if you want your div to hide the overflow you must define a height.

Comment: height: 100%; helps - I set in wrong place :P Thanks for your help!